# Divide a page by a spiral binder

Tags: tikz-pgf, backgrounds

I need help for this (lesson plan) format by tikz.

[image]

Now, this is based on the answer from Schrödinger's cat.

[image]

Comment: If you want only to divide the page and add a spiral, this is easy. If you want someone to recreate the full page, you may have to wait a while. Do you have something that allows others to understand which document class you are using etc?

Comment: Yes, in the article class (like your answer). But the left side can be filled in with text. And other elements as shown in the image above.

Comment: You can add stuff on the left side with my answer, for instance using an overlay `tikzpicture`. However, I do not enjoy punching in texts from screen shots. So you can post what you have tried. The cleanest way is to ask a separate question for that.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This adds such a spiral binder.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage[inner=2.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\definecolor{mylightblue}{RGB}{185,204,222}
\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{117,150,175}
\definecolor{mydarkblue}{RGB}{19,36,75}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\tikzset{pics/spiral/.style={code={
\fill[black] (-0.8em,0) circle[radius=3pt] (0.8em,0) circle[radius=3pt];
\draw[line width=0pt,left color=mylightblue,right color=mylightblue,middle color=white] 
 (-0.8em,-1.5pt)arc[start angle=270,end angle=90,radius=1.5pt]
  -- (0.8em,1.5pt)arc[start angle=90,end angle=-90,radius=1.5pt] -- cycle;
}}}
\AddToShipoutPictureBG{\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\path (current page.north) coordinate (N) (current page.south) coordinate (S);
\ifodd\value{page}
 \path (current page text area.west) coordinate (W);
 \fill[mylightblue] ([xshift=-0.3em]W|-N) rectangle ([xshift=-1.3em]W|-S);
 \fill[myblue] ([xshift=-1.7em]W|-N) rectangle (current page.south west);
 \fill[mydarkblue] ([xshift=-2em]W|-N) rectangle ([xshift=-3em]W|-S);
 \path foreach \Y in {8,7,...,-8} 
  {([xshift=-1.6em,yshift=\Y cm]current page text area.west) pic{spiral}};
\else
 \path (current page text area.east) coordinate (E);
 \fill[mylightblue] ([xshift=0.3em]E|-N) rectangle ([xshift=1.3em]E|-S);
 \fill[myblue] ([xshift=1.7em]E|-N) rectangle (current page.south east);
 \fill[mydarkblue] ([xshift=2em]E|-N) rectangle ([xshift=3em]E|-S);
 \path foreach \Y in {8,7,...,-8} 
  {([xshift=1.6em,yshift=\Y cm]current page text area.east) pic[xscale=-1]{spiral}};
\fi 
\end{tikzpicture}}
%
\titleformat{\section}[display]{}{}{0pt}
  {\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={(title.base)}]
  \node[fill=mydarkblue,text=white,font=\LARGE\bfseries\sffamily,outer sep=0pt,
    inner ysep=1ex] (title) {#1};
  \fill[mydarkblue] ([xshift=-1pt]title.south east) --
  ([xshift=0.95\linewidth-1.5em]title.south west)
  to[out=180,in=0]
   ([xshift=0.95\linewidth-3em]title.north west)
   -- ([xshift=-1pt]title.north east);
  \fill[mylightblue] ([xshift=0.95\linewidth-1.5em]title.south west)
   -- ++ (1.5em,0) 
  to[out=180,in=0] ([xshift=0.95\linewidth-2em]title.north west)
  -- ++ (-1.5em,0)  to[out=0,in=180] cycle;
  \fill[myblue] ([xshift=0.95\linewidth-2.7em]title.south west)
   -- ++ (0.8em,0) 
  to[out=180,in=0] ([xshift=0.95\linewidth-3.9em]title.north west)
  -- ++ (-0.8em,0)  to[out=0,in=180] cycle;
 \end{tikzpicture}}[]

\titleformat{name=\section,numberless}[display]{}{}{0pt}
 {\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={(title.base)}]
  \node[fill=mydarkblue,text=white,font=\LARGE\bfseries\sffamily,outer sep=0pt,
    inner ysep=1ex] (title) {#1};
  \fill[mydarkblue] ([xshift=-1pt]title.south east) --
  ([xshift=0.95\linewidth-1.5em]title.south west)
  to[out=180,in=0]
   ([xshift=0.95\linewidth-3em]title.north west)
   -- ([xshift=-1pt]title.north east);
  \fill[mylightblue] ([xshift=0.95\linewidth-1.5em]title.south west)
   -- ++ (1.5em,0) 
  to[out=180,in=0] ([xshift=0.95\linewidth-2em]title.north west)
  -- ++ (-1.5em,0)  to[out=0,in=180] cycle;
  \fill[myblue] ([xshift=0.95\linewidth-2.7em]title.south west)
   -- ++ (0.8em,0) 
  to[out=180,in=0] ([xshift=0.95\linewidth-3.9em]title.north west)
  -- ++ (-0.8em,0)  to[out=0,in=180] cycle;
 \end{tikzpicture}}[]
\newcommand{\OuterColumn}[2][]{\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\ifodd\value{page}
 \path ([xshift=-4em,yshift=1em]current page text area.north west)
  node[below left,matrix of nodes,nodes={text width=1.7in}]{
  #2
  };
\else
 \path ([xshift=4em,yshift=1em]current page text area.north east)
  node[below right,matrix of nodes,nodes={text width=1.7in}]{
  #2
  };
\fi  
\end{tikzpicture}}

\newsavebox{\mypic}
\sbox{\mypic}{\begin{tikzpicture}[thick,mylightblue]
\draw[clip] circle[radius=1.5cm];
\node{\includegraphics{example-image-duck}};
\end{tikzpicture}}

\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\section{A section}
\OuterColumn{%
~~~\usebox\mypic\\[1.5em]
|[fill=mylightblue,font=\large\bfseries]| PFT PFT\\
|[text=white]|{\begin{enumerate}
  \item bla
  \item blub
  \end{enumerate}}\\}%
\lipsum[1-2]
\clearpage

\section*{Another section}
\OuterColumn{%
|[fill=mylightblue,font=\large\bfseries]| PFT PFT\\
|[text=white]|{\begin{enumerate}
  \item bla
  \item blub
  \end{enumerate}}\\}%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You helped many teachers with this document. Many thanks.

Comment: @kalakay Thanks for the heads up and you're welcome!